# Status of Dhimmi on post-Islamic religions

Tags: other-religions, jizya

As I understand, the status of Dhimmi can be enjoyed by any non-Muslim religion as far it has a pact or treaty with the Islamic government were it lives and recognizes the authority (submits if you will) by among other things paying Jizya. But as I have notice most historical examples were this happened refer to pre-existing religions such as Judaism, Christianity, Buddhism and Hinduism.
Thus I wonder, to post-Islam religions can also be included on this deal? Cases like Sikhism, Bahaism, Mormonism, Rastafarianism, Wicca, Asatru and neo-Paganism in general, etc.?
Or there will be something precluding such deals and/or against accepting Jizya from such movements as they came after the founding of Islam?

Comment: The view of the Shafi'is and Hanbalis is that no one except the People of the Book and Magians can become dhimmis. So according to that view many of the religions you have asked about can not become dhimmis.

Answer (score -1):

Islam considers that Muhammad (PBUH) is the seal of the Prophets.

> 33:40 Muhammad is not the father of any of your men, but (he is) the Messenger of Allah, and the Seal of the Prophets: and Allah has full knowledge of all things.

As such, every religion that came after him even those that claimed to be monotheistic would be considered a case of apostasy instead, especially if they make Muslims leave Islam for theirs.

However whether members of other religions can switch among themselves (for example a Christian under Islamic rule that becomes a Bahai) is generally of no importance to Islam but such person might lost some of the benefits that comes with the Dhimmi status if they have it.

Some Muslims may see in a better light to switch from polytheism (like Hinduism) or atheism (like Buddhism) to a more monotheistic religion like Bahaism or Sikhism but that’s probably subjective and might depend on the individual.

Whether there’s a punishment for leaving Islam (apostasy) that’s a matter for other subject. Now in some cases some religious movements have been accepted in some Islamic societies as part of another already established and accepted religion. For example Sikhs are classified as Hindus in Malaysia and Indonesia for legal purposes, Taoists and followers of the Chinese Folk Religion as Buddhists in some Islamic countries, Mandeans are included among Christians in Iran IIRC, and so on. Whether this communities are ok with that is another matter, some are not, some in fact themselves came with that solution, but should be seen under individual basis and cultural contexts.

In the case of neo-Pagans due to their polytheistic nature and practice, at least in some cases, of certain sinful practices like magic, divination and superstitions, most Islamic scholars would argue their practices can’t be allowed under Islam. Muhammad (PBUH) did said that treaties with Pagans should be respected and their practices allowed under Dhimmi status and if they accepted to pay Jizya.

> 9:4 As for the polytheists who have honoured every term of their treaty with you and have not supported an enemy against you, honour your treaty with them until the end of its term. Surely Allah loves those who are mindful ˹of Him˺.

> 9:7 How can such polytheists have a treaty with Allah and His Messenger, except those you have made a treaty with at the Sacred Mosque? So, as long as they are true to you, be true to them. Indeed Allah loves those who are mindful ˹of Him˺.

This was actually what happened in Medina, but as eventually almost all Pagans disappeared on Islamic lands such treaties no longer exists and hardly modern neo-Pagans could claim to be the continuators. Some Islamic rulers also had similar treaties with polytheists from other areas like India, Indonesia and Malaysia mostly Hindus who still exists to this day, but most neo-Pagans do not see themselves as Hindus.

There’s an hypothetical scenario on whether Islam ever expands toward a region that already have this communities, for example Europe, and who were never Muslims to begin with. Presumably a new treaty can be reach in those cases.

So short answer:

- No, is very difficult for this groups to reach Dhimmi status as they’re not from the already existing religions that have them. They might be able to claim to be part of one but that would depend on a lot of factors including whether the recipient community and themselves would agree to such.
- Muslims who leave Islam whether by a newer or older religion are generally seen as Apostates.
- In the case of a new expansion or eventual growth of Islam making a new Islamic country the status could be reach after new negotiations as long as the members of this pre-existing communities are not ex Muslims.